# How to download and show images Asynchronously on a listview with CursorAdapter from bindView method

Tags: android

How to implement downloading images from server and showing them on a listview with Cursor adapter. I am able to download the images from url by executing AsyncTask from the bindView method of the CursorAdapter Class by passing the image url and ImageView in the constructor of the AsyncTask. But the problem is all the rows are getting populated with the same image and when the list is scrolled , the AsyncTask gets executed again for the rows that appear again after scrolling. I know this is a very common issue when downloading and showing images asynchronously in listview from getview (of ArrayAdapter) method as the Imageview reference in not provided to the Asynctask thread properly , all the solutions i found on web for this is provided for ArrayAdapter (using viewHolders or Weakreferences hashmaps etc) but i am not able to find any same work around with bindView method of CursorAdapter. Any help would be greatful.
My code goes here...

```
@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.group_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.tvSteps = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.tvMobile  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.pic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewF1);
        holder.mobtv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        holder.pbar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.prbar);
        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        //String mob = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_ADMIN_MOB));
        String group_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_GROUP_NAME));
        String admin_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_ADMIN_NAME));
        String image = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_GROUP_IMAGE));
        //int self_admin = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_SELF_ADMIN));
        //int steps = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_STEPS));
        //int group_id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_GROUP_ID));
        long date   = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FriendsDataProvider.COL_CREATE_DATE));

        /**
         * Next set the title of the entry.
         */
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        /*TextView tvgroup_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tvsteps_ = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tvMobile = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView grp_iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewF1);
        TextView mobtv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        ProgressBar pbar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.prbar);*/
        holder.pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.mobtv.setText("");
        holder.group_name
        .setText(Html
                .fromHtml("<font color = '#442E5B'></font><font>"
                        + group_name+ "</font>"));

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM/yy");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(Database.tz);
        holder.tvSteps.setText("Created On : "+dateFormat.format(date));
        holder.tvMobile.setText("Admin : "+admin_name+"\n " );
        if(image!=null&&image.length()>0){

            new GetImage(context, image, holder.pic, holder.pbar).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }else
            holder.pic
            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_add);


    }
```

and the GetImage class as ...

```
public class GetImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Bitmap bitmap ; 
         Context ctx;
         private final WeakReference<ImageView> viewReference;
         String photo_path;
         ProgressBar pbar;

        public GetImage(Context ctx,String image_path,ImageView iv,ProgressBar pbar) {
            super();
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.photo_path = image_path;
            this.pbar = pbar;
            viewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(iv);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... objects) {

            try
            {


                File file1 = new File(photo_path);
                String path1 = file1.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bitmap1 = null;

                if (path1 != null) {
                        bitmap1 = Profile.decodeFile(file1, 2);
                }

                if (bitmap1 != null) {
                    this.bitmap = bitmap1;

                } else 

                {


                Log.i("Profile", "photo text : "+photo_path);
                String[] path = photo_path.split("/");
                String urll = ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.url);
                String image_url = urll+"/uploads/"+path[path.length-1];
                Log.i("Profile", "image url : "+image_url);
                URL url = new URL(image_url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

               // String data1 = String.valueOf(String.format(u.photo));

                File miDirs = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FITGEN/Images");
                if (!miDirs.exists())
                    miDirs.mkdirs();




                String imageFilePath = String.format(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FITGEN/Images/"
                                + path[path.length-1]);

                File file = new File(imageFilePath);
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    Log.i("Profile", "File created name : "+file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
                byte[] byteArray = outstream.toByteArray();

                stream.write(byteArray);
                stream.close();
                ImageView iv = viewReference.get();
                iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getDrawingCache());
                iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                Bitmap scaledPicture = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, screenshot.getWidth(), screenshot.getHeight(), true);

                bitmap = scaledPicture;
            }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("Profile", "error in getimage : "+e.getMessage());//e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void o) { 
            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if(bitmap!=null)
            { 
                ImageView iv = viewReference.get();
                bitmap = Statics.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 10);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }  
            }  
       }
```

Comment: For effectively downloading and managing images in list view you should can below mention third party  libraries:https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader, http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @himanshumunjal - i have downloaded and added this lib but what i want to implement is... first to search for the image locally (in device) and if not found then download it from server and show on the imageview with a default drawable to be shown if both of the above fetching fails...please guide how to use this lib effectively for this purpose.